# Date Variable for last working day in UK?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on UK based project.

I put a lovely variable in to give me a start date and end date of the last working day for a Monday to Friday . Unfortuantely I wanted the start date time to be the start of the day and the end date to be the end of the day . What change can I make to make this happen ?

```
SET @Startdate =
  ( CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Startdate) = 7
      THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, @Startdate)
    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Startdate) = 1
      THEN DATEADD(DAY, (-2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Startdate)), @Startdate)
    ELSE
      DATEADD(DAY, -1, @Startdate)
  END )

SET @Enddate = 
  CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Enddate) = 7
      THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, @Enddate)
    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Enddate) = 1
      THEN DATEADD(DAY, (-2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Enddate)), @Enddate)
    ELSE
      DATEADD(DAY, -1, @Enddate) 
  END

print @Startdate 
print @Enddate
```

Results :

> Feb 26 2013 12:00AM
>   Feb 26 2013 12:00AM

I need `Feb 26 2013 00:00` until `Feb 27 2013 00:00`, so it covers all day Tuesday (the last working day if run today).

Comment: Can you show some example inputs? Such as what would be in `@startdate` & `@enddate` before calling the `SET` statements you provided?

Comment: SELECT STARTDATE = '27-FEB-2013'
SELECT ENDDATE = '27-FEB-2013' amperand not showing here

Comment: Wow, that is messy code. I highly recommend you [create a calendar table](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) and save yourself some serious headaches.

Comment: @JamesKhan: Do weekends actually matter? Or just given a specific `DATETIME` you want a `@start` representing the beginning of that day, and an `@end` that's the end of that day?

Comment: Additionally, you may be thinking about date/time the wrong way - end-of-day should always be thought of as 'less than the next day'

Comment: weekend matter in case someone runs it on saturday or sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solved problem if you perform a cursory Google search (lots of good UDFs for this), but to use your code as is, just add one to the @Enddate calculation if you really do want 26th 0:00 to 27th 0:00 (or add just below 1 like Kenneth Fisher suggests if you want 23:59, which seems better).

Comment: Uh, this is even _worse_ than Kenneth suggests, as there are even **more** 'unlisted' values.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear; I was referencing his comment to suggest subtracting a few MS rather than actually subtracting a whole minute.

Comment: Right, and subtracting a few MS is a terrible idea. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually 12:00AM is 00:00, you would just need to convert it in another format if you want (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Just add one day to Feb 26 12:00AM and you'll get Feb 27 12:00AM which is Feb 27 00:00.

Comment: I would recommend against just adding a day.  That is going to catch anyone who just entered Feb 27 2013.  Or the odd rare one that actually was 2/27/2013 00:00:00.  I would add a day then subtract 3 milliseconds (assuming datetime, look at the definition for datetime to see why 3ms.)  That will give you 2/26/2012 23:59:59.997 which is the last possible time (again for datetime) for 2/26/2013.

Comment: for those that don't want to Google `DATETIME` typically rounds to the nearest 3ms interval (`DATETIME` accuracy = ± 3ms). Just thought I'd supplement Kenneth's response.

Comment: @KennethFisher no, please, please, please don't use or recommend this `dateadd(millisecond, -3, ...` nonsense. [Here's why](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).